# playing files after accepting them through open dialog box

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, sdk

I am a new member and joined this site after referring to it loads of times when i was stuck with some programming problems. I am trying to code a media player (Win32 SDK VC++ 6.0) for my college project and I am stuck. I have searched on various forums and msdn and finally landed on the function GetShortPathName which enables me to play through folders and files which have a whitespace in their names. I will paste the code here so it will be much more clearer as to what i am trying to do.

```
case IDM_FILE_OPEN :
    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = "Media Files (All Supported Types)\0*.avi;*.mpg;*.mpeg;*.asf;*.wmv;*.mp2;*.mp3\0"
                                      "Movie File (*.avi;*.mpg;*.mpeg)\0*.avi;*.mpg;*.mpeg\0"
                                      "Windows Media File (*.asf;*.wmv)\0*.asf;*.wmv\0"
                                      "Audio File (*.mp2;*.mp3)\0*.mp2;*.mp3\0"
                                      "All Files(*.*)\0*.*\0";   
                    ofn.lpstrFile = szFileName;
                    ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
                    ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT | OFN_CREATEPROMPT;
                    ofn.lpstrDefExt = "mp3";

                    if(GetOpenFileName(&ofn))
                    {

                        length = GetShortPathName(szFileName, NULL, 0);
                        buffer = (TCHAR *) malloc (sizeof(length));
                        length = GetShortPathName(szFileName, buffer, length);

                        for(i = 0 ; i < MAX_PATH ; i++)
                        {
                            if(buffer[i] == '\\')
                                buffer[i] = '/';
                        }

                        SendMessage(hList,LB_ADDSTRING,0,(LPARAM)buffer);
                        mciSendString("open buffer alias myFile", NULL, 0, NULL);
                        mciSendString("play buffer", NULL, 0, NULL);
                    }

                    return 0;
```

using the GetShortPathName function i get the path as : D:/Mp3z/DEEPBL~1/03SLEE~1.mp3
Putting this path directly in Play button case

```
mciSendString("open D:/Mp3jh/DEEPBL~1/03SLEE~1.mp3 alias myFile", NULL, 0, NULL);
mciSendString("play myFile", NULL, 0, NULL);
```

the file opens and plays fine. But as soon as i try to open and play it through the open file dialog box, nothing happens. Any input appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think you need a short path name?

Comment: Don't use the short name. Just escape the spaces in the name by adding quotes to the file name: `"open \"path/to/file/with spaces in.mp3\" alias myFile"`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that you're passing the name of the `buffer` variable to the `mciSendString` function as a *string*, rather than passing the contents of the buffer.

You need to concatenate the arguments you want to pass (`open` and `alias myFile`) with the *contents* of `buffer`.

The code can also be much simplified by replacing `malloc` with an automatic array. You don't need to `malloc` it because you don't need it outside of the block scope. (And you shouldn't be using `malloc` in C++ code anyway; use `new[]` instead.)

Here's a modified snippet of the code shown in your question:
<sup>(Warning: changes made using only my eyes as a compiler! Handle with care.)</sup>

```
if(GetOpenFileName(&ofn))
{
    // Get the short path name, and place it in the buffer array.
    // We know that a short path won't be any longer than MAX_PATH, so we can
    // simply allocate a statically-sized array without futzing with new[].
    //
    // Note: In production code, you should probably check the return value
    // of the GetShortPathName function to make sure it succeeded.
    TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetShortPathName(szFileName, buffer, MAX_PATH);

    // Add the short path name to your ListBox control.
    //
    // Note: In C++ code, you should probably use C++-style casts like
    // reinterpret_cast, rather than C-style casts!
    SendMessage(hList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(buffer));

    // Build the argument string to pass to the mciSendString function.
    // 
    // Note: In production code, you probably want to use the more secure
    // alternatives to the string concatenation functions.
    // See the documentation for more details.
    // And, as before, you should probably check return values for error codes.
    TCHAR arguments[MAX_PATH * 2];   // this will definitely be large enough
    lstrcat(arguments, TEXT("open"));
    lstrcat(arguments, buffer);
    lstrcat(arguments, TEXT("alias myFile"));
    // Or, better yet, use a string formatting function, like StringCbPrintf:
    // StringCbPrintf(arguments, MAX_PATH * 2, TEXT("open %s alias myFile"),
    //                buffer);

    // Call the mciSendString function with the argument string we just built.
    mciSendString(arguments, NULL, 0, NULL);
    mciSendString("play myFile", NULL, 0, NULL);
}
```

Do note that, as the above code shows, working with C-style strings (character arrays) is a real pain in the ass. C++ provides a better alternative, in the form of the `std::string` class. You should strongly consider using that instead. To call Windows API functions, you'll still need a C-style string, but you can get one of those by using the `c_str` method of the `std::string` class.

Comment: Thank you guys. I used strcpy and strcat and it worked. Thanks Cody Gray for the code. It's similar to what i did.